# Javascript event.target does not output as expected in ReactJs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the below ReactJs component:

```
import React from 'react';

const TestOptions = (props) => (
    <li className={props.className} onClick={(event) => props.clickTestOptions(event)}>
        {
            React.createElement(
                'div',
                {
                    className: 'opt-wrap',
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
                        __html: props.details.answer
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    </li>
);

export default TestOptions;
```

In parent component I have the following function.

```
clickTestOptions = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

The console sometime give me either one of the following result:

```
<div class="opt-wrap">Mathematics</div>
```

or,

```
<li class="mc-opt-cls"><div class="opt-wrap">Mathematics</div></li>
```

I need always the li element not the div, What is the solution?

Comment: This is due to event bubbling and has nothing to do with React in particular.

Comment: Any solution with JavaScript?

Comment: `onClick` on child and `event.stopPropagation()` in it. Also keep in mind that events in React are _synthetic_, meaning you should never pass around references to them. `console.log(event.target)` is passing the `event.target` reference to an async function (`console.log`) so what is logged in the console might not be the same as the value at the time of calling `console.log`.

Comment: My main goal is to catch the parent ul element on clicking the li. It will easy to catch the ul element when I am sure what is returned by the event.target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), which always refers to the element the listener is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

For now my solution is:

```
let targetOpt = event.target;
console.log('targetOpt:', targetOpt);

if (!targetOpt.classList.contains("mc-opt-cls")) {
    targetOpt = findParentWithClass(event.target, 'mc-opt-cls');
}

console.log('targetOpt:', targetOpt);
```

findParentWithClass is my helper function:

```
export const findParentWithClass = (el, cls)=> {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls));
    return el;
};
```